# JSON Nested Object Parsing

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

My website utilizes $.getJSON("filename.json") to load a JSON object from a local file. However, I've been having difficulty parsing this object; I often receive a "undefined" console log message. The JSON file has been verified, and I believe that array syntax (as listed below) is the correct access method...

```
var data = $.getJSON("summer.json");
console.log(data["ResponseJSON"]);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESS7d.jpg

Comment: What was it in [the documentation and examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) that made you think that code would work? Even if the call were synchronous, JavaScript is case-sensitive, and the property name is `responseJSON`, not `ResponseJSON` (and the call almost certainly isn't synchronous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the value and use the value in the callback function like this. Because the data is returned asynchronously.

If you put the console.log outside the callback, it will be evaluated before the data arrives.

```
$.getJSON('summer.json', function(d) {
    data = d;
    console.log(data["ResponseJSON"]);
});
```

Comment: You also have to *use* the data from the callback, or from a function called from there and being passed the data.

Comment: Is there a reason that the data must be used within (or in a function called from) the callback function?

For instance, why wouldn't

    `var data;
    $.getJSON('summer.json', function(d) {
        data = d;
    });
    console.log(data["ResponseJSON"]);`

function correctly?

Comment: @MichaelHang because the data is returned asynchronously. If you put the console.log outside the callback, it will be evaluated before the data arrives.

Comment: ... And that's why I added the first comment :)